# The position of suddenly in passives

Tags: grammar, stative-verbs

In the corpora I've found examples like:

> They were suddenly disconnected.

> They were suddenly freed up.

I couldn't find examples when suddenly in the position like above occurs with stative verbs. Are these sentences degraded?

> She was suddenly loved by many.

> They were suddenly liked in some circles.

Are these sentences better if we replace 'to be' with 'get'? Like:

> She got suddenly loved by many.

Comment: What does "degraded" mean here? Are you asking whether they "don't sound so good" that way?

Comment: He was suddenly alive/dead. It was suddenly flat all across the desert. _Sudden_ has to refer to some event (maybe a transition between states) that can change rapidly. That doesn't describe most stative predicates.

Comment: Curiously, "he was suddenly famous" [is attested](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20was%20suddenly%20famous%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en).

Comment: @tchrist I suspect that OP meant "deprecated", but even that isn't really the right word there.

Comment: Your sentences are not at all idiomatic. A native speaker would express the idea differently, for example "She suddenly found herself very popular."

Comment: It's not very idiomatic, but "They were suddenly liked in some circles" is easily understood. And I found 2 examples in COCA: "He suddenly liked, even loved her." "Holly Thorne, who suddenly liked her name, knew where she was going and why."

Comment: The broadening of stative verbs to include the inchoative sense ('She was suddenly famous'; 'He suddenly felt well again') is well known but non-uniformly distributed. 'She was suddenly loved by many' doesn't sound too bad (and I'm not sure that the use of the passive is relevant). 'She was suddenly tolerated by many' doesn't sound too natural. 'The keys were suddenly remembered' sounds very odd, but in this case the active transform 'He suddenly remembered the keys' is far more natural.

Answer (score 1):

When you add "suddenly" to a stative verb, it forces an inchoative interpretation; "he was suddenly loved" only makes sense if you interpret it as "he suddenly came to be loved." This reinterpretation of a stative verb can be rather infelicitous, which likely explains its rarity in corpora. This is just an issue of semantics; "suddenly" cannot describe a state but only a change.

I'm not sure if this happens more often in the passive or the active voice; it may be that this is less well attested in the passive voice only because the passive voice is *in general* less common, or this may have something to do with combining inchoative interpretations with the passive voice.